# How to get number inside a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get a number inside a `div` and use it as a `number` in JavaScript/jQuery? Here is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="number">25</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var numb = $('.number').val();
console.log(numb);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9rLfba/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9rLfba/3/

Comment: unless its an input element (input,textarea,select) jQuery wrapped elements do not have a .val() method, use `.html` or `.text` methods

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.val()` is for getting the value of form elements like `input`, `select`, etc. You can't use it on `div`s. You can use `.text()` to get the text content of the `div` element.

```
var number = $('.number').text();
```

But it will return the content as a string. To convert it to a Javascript number, you have to use `parseInt()`:

```
var number = parseInt($('.number').text());
```

Comment: what if the element is a mixture of characters and a number. And I want to extract the number only. If we apply your code the outcome is NaN.

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni I agree, my code only assumes that the content of the element are just numeric characters in which `parseInt` would work. But it shouldn't be difficult to tweak to support your scenario. We could for example remove the non-numeric characters first before attempting to `parseInt` :)

Comment: Yes. In my case I added a span around it and applied your method. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

```
var numb = $('.number').text();
console.log(parseInt(numb));
```

Comment: You should mention why this works along with the code so that OP and others know what is going on