# How to find the all numbers inside the div and add <span></span> tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `DOM` like this

```
<div class="main_div">
    <p>A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?</p>    
</div>
```

i just want to add span tag to all numbers like

```
<div class="main_div">
    <p>A car averages <span> 27 </span> miles per gallon. If gas costs $<span>4.04</span> per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel <span>2,727</span> typical miles?</p>    
</div>
```

I have tried so may ways and check this links too

[Javascript/jquery get number value inside of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347393/javascript-jquery-get-number-value-inside-of-element)

[How to get number inside a div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319183/how-to-get-number-inside-a-div-with-jquery)

[Jquery - Adding all numbers inside span of a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924431/jquery-adding-all-numbers-inside-span-of-a-particular-class)

but this can only select first numbers only i want to select all number inside the div , if the div contains 20 numbers i just need to add span all numbers , is this possible ? best answers must be appreciated ..

Comment: @vijayP It's numbers with `.` as decimal point and `,` as thousands separator.

Comment: @LinkinTED could you tell me how can you find this is duplicate, because i have search so many way and i have added the links to my question but i cant find this one ?

Comment: @trincot can you tell me this ?

Comment: @JishnuVS:  https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+wrap+all+numbers+in+a+div

Comment: @LinkinTED sorry for this i am asking how would you know about this is a duplicate question ? when i write the question stackoverflow give me suggessions and i have check all links but i dont get this one, thats why i am asking you

Comment: if i get the right answer it may not happend again thats why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex to match number and wrap in in `<span>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main_div p').each(function() {
    $(this).html(
      $(this).text().replace(/([0-9]+[.,][0-9]+|[0-9]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>')
    );
  })
});
```

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <p>A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles? I am years old 24, because of 24.</p>
  <p>A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This duplicates the text. I don't understand why this gathers votes.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, my bad. Edited

Comment: *"Wouldn't that also replace `my age is 24. I am old` to `my age is <span>24.</span> I am old`?"* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use regex on the divs `html` (or `text` if you are afraid to mess with the html).

replace the regex matches using a function that takes the match. Also makes it a lot easier to handle potential edge cases.

```js
var html = jQuery("div.main_div").html();
console.log(html);
html = html.replace(/(\d*,\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+)/ig, function(match) {
  return '<span style="background-color:yellow">' + match + '</span>';
});
console.log(html);
jQuery("div.main_div").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <p>A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?</p>
</div>
```

The regex consists of 3 capture tokens:

`\d*,\d+|` matches any amount of `digit` followed by one `.` followed by at least one `digit`.

`\d*\.\d+` matches any amount of `digit` followed by one `,` followed by at least one `digit`.

`\d+` matches at least one `digit`.

Comment: Wouldn't that also replace `my age is 24. I am old` to `my age is <span>24.</span> I am old`?

Comment: It would. I'll change the regex